# React Native - Unable to call method from another component

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I have two very simple classes. All I am trying to do is call a method from another component that will print text to the console. When the user clicks the navigate button in class 2, it should call the _printtest function in class 1, unfortunately, that is not happening.

Class 1

```
 class drawerControl extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._printtest = this._printtest.bind(this);
  };

  _printtest(){
    console.log("Hello World");
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Home 
            openControlPanel={this.openControlPanel.bind(this)}
            functest={this._printtest}>
        </Home>
    );
  } 
}
```

Class 2

```
class Home extends Component {

   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.callPrint = this.callPrint.bind(this);
    }
    callPrint(){
        this.props.functest()
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.callPrint} style=  {styles.button}>
              <Text>Navigate</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      } 

}
```

Either I get an error that says "this.props.functest" is not a function, or nothing happens at all. This seems like something that should be extremely simple. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into a fresh react-native project and tested it on my Android phone.

1. You need to use CamelCase for custom components, afaik: `DrawerControl`
2. The `DrawerControl` class is missing `openControlPanel() {}`
3. Main problem: calling `console.log()` prints to the iOS console. You need to run `react-native log-ios` in a terminal in order to view output, otherwise it'll appear as if nothing happend.

The error you mentioned about `this.props.functest` not being a function can occur in multiple ways, it should't happen with the code you posted here though, provided you make the changes I listed.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I made the changes you suggested, but the ios-log prints "assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801..." every time I click the button. Also, the openControlPanel() is present in my actual code, I'm just not using it.

Comment: This might be a bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9218

Comment: I only receive that error when I make this call: this.props.functest, otherwise, if i make this call: this.props.functest() i still get the "not a function" error. Though If I put the function in my index.ios.js file it works for some reason.

Comment: Try this: `<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.functest} ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `props` is already a function. So you do not need to call it like `this.props.functest()`. Just simply call like

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.functest}}>
    <Text>Navigate</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I try to make a simple app via RNPlay base on your code and it works.
https://rnplay.org/apps/2LJnbg

Answer (score 0):

in your Class 1 change following.

```
<Home 
  openControlPanel={this.openControlPanel.bind(this)}
  functest={this._printtest()}>
</Home>
```

you need to call `_printtest` function

Answer (score -2):

If you do not set `props` you will not be able to use it. `props` is just an argument for the constructor and is not an attribute of you instance meaning `this.props` is undefined. However you could set `this.props = props` in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I still receive the same error even when setting props in my constructor.

Comment: This is not true; `props` is set by React.